# Is possible to change firmware of ev3 brick?

Tags: ev3

I bought LEGO 31313 but I would like to change the firmware for education (45544).

1.09H to 1.09E.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Connect EV3 with USB to computer, have Lego Mindstorm software open

Under Tools -> Select Firmware update and start he update

Brick will restart after firmware is updated

Comment: This is the correct method. If you have the retail software downloaded, you will need to download and install the educational software [here](https://education.lego.com/en-us/downloads/mindstorms-ev3/software) in order to access the 1.09E firmware and utilize its additional features (datalogging, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is totally possible and I have done it multiple times. You will need access to both firmware files though - AFAIK there is no menu to choose versions.

Comment: Thanks Phil, can you explain how to... or may be there's some manual or video to do it... I'm newbie and i would like to do it. Thank you very much